# Loading class which have only static methods

Tags: java, jdbc

I have a class `MyClass` that has a static variable. Class implements smth like singleton(it has `java.sql.DataSource` as static variable and has method `getConnection()` which checks whether DataSource variable is not null and if it is null - obtains the connection, else - return `dataSource.getConnection()`) 
When I call `MyClass.getConnection()` method for the first time the class is loaded to the memory and DataSource variable is obtained. Will this class stay in memory while the program is running or it will be garbage collected when the control flow of the program will exit outside the method where  `MyClass.getConnection()` was invoked?
Actually I want to know whether I have to obtain Connection object in each method(obtaining connection object is rather long operation, isn't it?) where I use it or only once in some place?

**edit**
This is my class that obtains a connection

```
public class ResourceManager {

    private static DataSource dataSource;


    public static synchronized Connection getConnection() throws NamingException, SQLException {
        if (dataSource == null) {
            Locale.setDefault(Locale.ENGLISH);
            Context context = (Context) new InitialContext().lookup("java:comp/env");
            dataSource = (DataSource) context.lookup("jdbc/Project");
            context.close();
        }
        return dataSource.getConnection();
    }


    public static void close(Connection con) {
        if (con != null)
            try {
            con.close();
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(ResourceManager.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }


    public static void close(ResultSet rs) {
        if (rs != null)
            try {
            rs.close();
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(ResourceManager.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }


    public static void close(PreparedStatement stmt) {
        if (stmt != null)
            try {
            stmt.close();
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(ResourceManager.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
}
```

in this class I obtain connection from tomcat pool

So, if in one method I call ResourseManager.getConnection() and it obtains the datasource, will it be the same datasource when I call this method after some time passed or it will be GC?

P.S. I use close methods in finally blocks

Comment: I've tried to understand your question, but it is hard. Can you improve the formatting so that we can see what you are asking?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Will this class stay in memory while
>   the program is running or it will be
>   garbage collected when the control
>   flow of the program will exit outside
>   the method where
>   MyClass.getConnection() was invoked?

Class objects will become eligible for garbage collection just like any other object - when no references exist to the Class objects. Typically, these references are held by the ClassLoader that loaded the Class in the first place. So, the class will stay as long as the Classloader that references it, is in use. It will not be unloaded after method execution, unless the Classloader was created by the caller, and the reference to the classloader no longer exists.

In long running applications (like Java EE applications), the class and the classloader (a unique one will typically exist for every application) will not be eligible for garbage collection, until the application itself is brought down.

**The singleton pattern and its effect on GC**

The garbage collection of classes that implement the singleton pattern is a unique situation. The class continues to be referenced by its instance, so it will never be eligible for garbage collection. This could lead to problems where the classloaders themselves may not be garbage collected, especially during application restarts in a container, thus leading to a memory leak. The solution to prevent such a problem, is to destroy the singleton instance in a context listener that listens for the context (application) destruction event.

**Update #2**

For the updated question:

> Actually I want to know whether I have to obtain Connection object in each method(obtaining connection object is rather long operation, isn't it?) where I use it or only once in some place?

Obtaining a connection is expensive, but only if you manage the connection. That's why you use a datasource backed by a connection pool. Everytime you need a connection, the datasource will fetch one from the pool. Once you are done with the connection, you should close it, so that it can be returned to the pool. My advice is to not perform premature optimizations; connection pools are a fact in modern Java EE applications, and application servers perform enough optimization to ensure that there is very little latency here. IMHO, a properly tuned pool will give you better performance than a hand-crafted class put in place to centralize access to connection objects.

Comment: I don't think that this is correct.  By default the JVM will GC unused classes. But static variables are a GC root, so that once a class with a singleton has been initialised it will not be GC'd because the singleton will be an instance of the class. Set the singleton to null and the class can be GC'd if there are no other instances.

Comment: ++ to Vineet. You are better off creating a singleton that obtains the connection. But then don't forget to have a clean up method and/or put the release connection in the finalize() method so it can be released correctly on collection of the singleton. You might be better off having a regular class than trying to do something fancy with a static class. Trust me. I just did this on something I was working on. A regular instantiated class was cleaner.

Comment: @Duncan, the JLS allows for reclaiming classes only when the classloader is eligible for reclamation: `An implementation of the Java programming language may unload classes. A class or interface may be unloaded if and only if its defining class loader may be reclaimed by the garbage collector as discussed in §12.6.`

Comment: @Duncan, you are right however, that given the presence of the singleton, the class itself will never be eligible for reclamation unless the shutdown process of the application will nullify the singleton instance.

Comment: @Chris: Do you mean have an actual connection stored in a Singleton? If so, that is a very dangerous pattern for a wide variety of reasons (scalability comes immediately to mind).

Comment: @Duncan: If the Singleton is static, it will remain in memory until the application shuts down. You can empty out a class method (as opposed to an instance method), but it will not GC like an instance method and it will remain there, albeit null, until the application shuts down.

Comment: @Vinnet So, should i not to use static variable DataSource, but simply obtain datasource in getConnection method and return connection from this datasource immediatly?

Comment: If the singleton is only referenced by the class, and the class only by the singleton and classloader, and the classloader only by this class, shouldn't the garbage collector be able to clean this up?

Comment: @maks, use dependency injection if you can, to inject the DataSource objects at the point of need; then you can call getConnection() freely on the DS object. If you do not want to do dependency injection, avoid looking up the DataSource in the JNDI context first (this is performance intensive for every connection); you can store the DS reference in the resource manager, and return connections from it.

Comment: @Paulo, no the garbage collector will not clean up the singleton in that case. GC occurs for objects unreachable from GC roots. The singleton, it's class and the classloader will all be reachable from the thread stack (which is a GC root) or from the static member variable (which is a GC root).

Comment: @Vineet actually, in the example above i store reference in the resource manager. Thanks for help

Comment: @maks, I missed the if block. Also, I'm unsure about the need to synchronize on the DataSource object. It is most likely unnecessary. If you cannot use DI, use the (now deprecated) [ServiceLocator pattern](http://java.sun.com/blueprints/corej2eepatterns/Patterns/ServiceLocator.html).

Comment: maybe synchronize will avoid returning the same connection to different users if they simultaneously try to get connection?
Just came to mind: if I check for null in getconnection so every user will get the only one datasource from connection pool, because every time resource manager will return the same connection from the  only one datasource. Am I wrong?

Comment: @maks, I don't think so. If that were the case, even injected data source objects would need synchronization, which is not the case. Only a poorly programmed data source will exhibit the behavior that you've described.

Comment: Just came to mind: if I check for null in getconnection so every user will get the only one datasource from connection pool, because every time resource manager will return the same connection from the only one datasource. Am I wrong?

Comment: @Vineet hmm, my ResourceManager is not a kind of serviceLocator pattern, is it?

Comment: @maks, if it returned only the DataSource to a client class, I would have considered it to be a service locator. The current class however has too many responsibilities. It would be better to return the DS to the client, and have the Connection, PreparedStatement and other objects managed by the client.

Comment: @maks, as far as returning datasources from the pool, well that concept is incorrect. A datasource has access to a pool of physical connection objects. However, it never returns a physical connection to the client; it always returns a logical wrapper around the connection object. That way, the client never gets to create or close the real connection; all of this activity is done by the pool. You can provide the datasource object to multiple clients. If the datasource implementation is threadsafe, different connection wrappers will be returned to multiple clients in a thread safe manner.

Comment: @Gregory -- sorry to take a while. New baby in the family. No, actually I recommend against using singletons for maintaining database connections for the reason you mention about cleaning them up. I prefer to have a class that I can instantiate to maintain the connections and then I can better assure it is cleaned up with an explicit cleanUp method and then I can override the finalize method to make sure cleanUp is called to make sure the connections are released.

Answer (score 0):

When you deal with static methods, etc., they do not belong to an instance. As such, they are not garbage collected when instances are collected. Instead, they stay in memory. In theory, they should stay in memory until the application in question is terminated. As long as it continues to run, the static items stay in memory.

What this means to you? if you are shutting down the application, the Singleton will be set for collection and collected at some point in time. Otherwise, it will stay there.