# Tomcat internal error

Tags: java, tomcat

I have an AuthorizationServlet which is called when user click button in login page. Here is a piece of code of servlet's doPost method:

```
        AuthorizationBean bean = new AuthorizationBean();
        String login = (String) request.getSession().getAttribute("login");
        String password = (String) request.getSession().getAttribute("password");
        try {
            UserType type = bean.getRoleOfUser(login, password);
            switch(type) {
                ...
            }
        } catch (DaoException ex) {
            throw new ServletException(ex.getMessage());
        }
```

I have omited some code, because it is doesn't apply the problem. Actually, `DaoException` can be thrown only in this line `UserType type = bean.getRoleOfUser(login, password);`
In method `getRoleOfUser` I do the connection to the database using tomcat's connection pool(Description of how I get the connection is in the first post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6317499/loading-class-which-have-only-static-methods))

Also here is my context.xml which creates the resource of db connection:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context antiJARLocking="true" path="/Project">
    <Resource name="jdbc/Project" auth="Container"
        type="javax.sql.DataSource" maxActive="100"
        maxIdle="30" maxWait="10000"
        username="name"
        password="password"
        driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"
        url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@127.0.0.1:1521:XE"/>
</Context>
```

When the AuthorizationServlet is called I get such error:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: Error instantiating servlet class com.tspp.common.AuthorizationServlet
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProcessor.process(Http11AprProcessor.java:864)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11AprProtocol.java:579)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$Worker.run(AprEndpoint.java:1665)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
root cause

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/tspp/dao/exceptions/DaoException
    java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2389)
    java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2699)
    java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:326)
    java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:308)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProcessor.process(Http11AprProcessor.java:864)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11AprProtocol.java:579)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$Worker.run(AprEndpoint.java:1665)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
root cause

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.tspp.dao.exceptions.DaoException
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1680)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1526)
    java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2389)
    java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2699)
    java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:326)
    java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:308)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProcessor.process(Http11AprProcessor.java:864)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11AprProtocol.java:579)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$Worker.run(AprEndpoint.java:1665)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

I have tried to debug it, but the debugger even didn't get to the servlets doPost method.
Actually last 2 exceptions are thrown when I start the program(before the servlet activation)

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: What does your deployment look like(EAR, WAR, etc.)? and where does the DAOException class reside in the final deployment. Is it a class in the WEB-INF directory? Is is jarred up?

Comment: I run the project through netbeans ide. DaoException class resides in WEB-INF directory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you have all your classes in `WEB-INF/classes`

Comment: But I have all classes in WEB-INF/classes

Comment: perhaps that particular one isn't there. That's what the exception says.

Comment: The bytecode of class DaoException is in build/web/WEB-INF/classes/com/tspp/DAO/exceptions folder of my netbeans project. Maybe the problem is that class name contains ...dao... and the path to bytecode of class contains ...DAO... But I didn't change it, my ide has genereated such path

Comment: by conventions, package names should be all lower case. Make the directory, `package` statement in DaoException.java and the `import` statement all match in case.

Comment: @matt all of that are in lower case. But ide generate DAO folder name in upper case

Comment: Then manually change the directory case yourself. They can't all be lower case if the directory name is still in upper case. Also, I'm not sure what IDE you are using or if it is generating a directory like `DAO` because of something you told it to do, but consider using a IDE that doesn't do such a boneheaded thing

Comment: interesting thing, when i manually change the folder name all works fine, but when I delete the build folder and run the project again, the folder that contains DaoException class still has DAO(uppercase) folder in path. i didn't change anything in my netbeans ide.

Comment: change your package definition: `package com.tspp.dao.exceptions`

Comment: but it has this name from the beginning

Comment: Well, perhaps you've told NetBeans to do that somehow. It's not expected behaviour. Try upgrading, cleaning, or switching IDE (NetBeans is not my IDE of choice due to such nasty bugs)

Answer (score 1):

Your class `com/tspp/dao/exceptions/DaoException` is not found by the JVM (`System.loadClass()` method) and hence you're having a `ClassNotFoundException`.

Make sure your code are compiled and included in `WEB-INF\classes` folder in your project. If it's in a jar, make sure the class is found in the JAR.